# mongoDB, I can use the auto generated ObjectId in another field when doing an insertOne?

Tags: mongodb

When inserting a new document, mongoDB automatically generates the "_id" with an ObjectId.
I ask if it is possible that when inserting, it can take the value that will be put in that "_id" in another field of the document.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course, that's possible. Try `db.collection.updateMany({}, [{$set: {id2: "$_id"}}])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_id value is automatically generated by the server if one isn't provided by the client (i.e. application).

You can provide any _id value you wish explicitly, it just has to be unique within its collection.